# What is the difference between read+write and read+write+truncate?

Tags: c++, linux

This is an easy question, but I couldn't find an explanation anywhere

I'm using fopen in C++, and I have the option to either use

"r+b" (Read and Write)

Or

w+b" (Read Write and Truncate)

What is the meaning of Truncate? What is the difference between "r+b" and "w+b"?
I understand the mathematical meaning of truncate is removing precision after a certain number of decimal points, but I don't understand the exact meaning in the C++ context.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"truncate" means that the file will be set to size `0` on opening.

`"w+b"` will give you an empty file (creating it if it didn't exist) that you can read and write to.

`"r+b"` will fail if the file does not exist;  and if the file does exist then the file remains unchanged for now and you can read or write to it.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `r+b` and `w+b` is that `r+b` keeps any existing data in the file intact, whereas `w+b` will remove (truncate) any data in the file, as if you had created a new file or opened it with `w`.

The same applies to the non-binary modifiers `r+` and `w+`.